# A given line has an origin of 5 and forms a 22º angle with the X axis, and is tangent with a point P on a given circle. What are the coordinates of P?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

A given line has an origin of 5 and forms a 22º angle with the X axis. It is also tangent with a point P on a given circle. What are the coordinates of P?

[image: Figure]

Comment: What does "an origin of $5$" mean?

Comment: y = 5 when x = 0

Comment: So you can use trig to find the gradient of the line. You can then find the equation of the line. Then find where it touches the circle.

Comment: I've added a figure.

Comment: That's called the "y-intercept" of the line, not the "origin". Also, in your figure the circle appears to be centered at the origin, which is the point (x,y)=(0,0). But if you aren't sure where the circle is, then the problem cannot be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

We need to find points on the circle with slope of the tangent equal to the slope of the line.

From the figure we have that the circle is centered in the origin thus to find P it suffice to find the equation of the line through the origin and ortogonal to the given line.

Remember that the condition for orthogonality is

$$m_1\cdot m_2=-1\implies m_2=-\frac{1}{m_1}$$

with

- $m_1=-\arctan22°$ is the slope of the given line
- $m_2$ is the slope of the line orthogonal to the given

Then P can be found by the intersection of the two lines.

Comment: Check the figure I added.

Comment: ok, then the circle is centered at the origin and as equation $x^2+y^2=R^2$, I add another hint!

Comment: How do I get R?

Comment: You don't need R, follow the hints I've given, can you see why it works?

Comment: Ah, I get it. Thanks.